# If x and y are different integers , and if $2005 +x =y^2 ; 2005+y =x^2 $ then find xy...

Tags: number-theory, functional-equations

Problem :

If $2005 +x =y^2 ; 2005+y =x^2$ then find xy...

My approach :

Let $2005 +x =y^2 .....(i) ; 2005+y =x^2 ......(ii) $

Now from (i) we get :

$ y = \sqrt{x + 2005}$

Now putting this value of y in (ii) we get :

$ \Rightarrow 2005 +\sqrt{x + 2005} =x^2$

$ \Rightarrow \sqrt{x + 2005} =x^2 -2005 $

Now squaring both sides we  get :

$\Rightarrow (\sqrt{x + 2005})^2 =(x^2 - 2005)^2$

Is there any other way I can solve this problem please suggest... thanks.

Comment: Somebody goofed up. If that wasn't me, there are no such $x,y$.

Comment: I am guessing that the condition $x,y\in\mathbb{Z}$ is a mistake because of how nicely the answer turns out if the condition is dropped (see sasuke4598's answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am new here so don't know how to type math equation but I am providing the solution.

2005+x=y^2  ..(1)
 2005+y=x^2 ..(2)

After subtracting 2nd equation from first
x-y=y^2-x^2
x-y=(x-y)(x+y)
(x-y)+(x-y)(x+y)=0     (we change the sign x-y to y-x here)
(x-y)(x+y+1)=o
because as mentioned x and y are different integers so x-y!=0
In this case
x+y+1=0  -> x+y=-1 ...(3)

Now adding equation (1) and second we got
4010+x+y=x^2+y^2
because x+y=-1
so 4010-1=x^2+y^2
4009=x^2+y^2
because x^2+y^=(x+y)^2-2xy
as (x+y)^2=x^2+y^2+2xy

so 4009=(x+y)^2-2xy
and 4009=(-1)^2-2xy

and 2xy=1-4009
xy=-2004

Comment: [Here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) are some hints to get you started on typing math here.

Answer (score 4):

*Hint:* $$2005 + x- (2005+y)=y^2 - x^2 \quad \Longrightarrow \quad (x-y)(x+y+1) = 0.$$

Answer (score 0):

$2005 +x =y^2 .....(i) ; 2005+y =x^2 ......(ii)$
$(i)-(ii)\Leftrightarrow (x-y).(x+y+1)=0$
$\Rightarrow x=y ; x+y=-1$
$+x=y$, now we solve $x,y$ then $xy=...$
$+x+y=-1 \Rightarrow xy=-2004$